# Multiline regex layout

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a regex: `Regex("((group1)(group2))(group3)")`

I'd like to format it in a way that looks nice and clear, i.e.:

```
(
  (group1)
  (group2)
)
(group3)
```

For example I've tried this:

```
Regex("("
    +   "(group1)"
    +   "(group2)"
    + ")"
    + "(group3)")     //--> loses the syntax highlighting in Intellij and a bit messy

Regex("""(
           (group1)
           (group2)
         )
         (group3)""") //--> not bad, but not equivalent (adds spaces and \n characters)
```

**Is there a way to have a clean layout while keeping the regex equivalent to the original and the syntax highlighting?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you still can use  the [`COMMENTS`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex-option/-c-o-m-m-e-n-t-s.html#comments) modifier (or `(?x)` inline version):

```
Regex("""(?x)(          # Group 1
              (group1)  # Group 2
              (group2)  # Group 3
             )
             (group3)  # Another group"""
```

See [`COMMENTS`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex-option/-c-o-m-m-e-n-t-s.html#comments) `RegexOption` reference:

> Permits whitespace and comments in pattern.

The `#` symbols must be escaped if they denote a literal `#` symbol in the pattern.

Note that literal spaces are also considered to be formatting whitespace, even inside character classes. Escape them if you need to match a literal space: `"""(?x)free\ spacing"""` or `"""(?x)[a-zA-Z\ ]+"""`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I got stuck on escaping charcaters though so you may want to add to your answer that regex escape only need one \ in the "triple quote" string. So for a number it is `"""   \d   """` and not `"""  \\d  """`

Comment: Well, inside triple quoted string literals, to define a literal backslash, one just needs to use ``\``, and inside regular string literals (that allow escape sequences like `\n`, `\r`, etc.) to define a literal backslash, one needs two - `"\\"`.

Comment: I see, I made a mistake when formatting the examples at the end of the answer. I used `<code>` tags for the first, and backticks for the second, and got tricked myself. Fixed.